# Database to declared variable

Tags: c#, database

I do want to pass StudName contents to my declared variable. i tried " +a.ToString+" But still i got errors

```
string a;

connection.Close();
connection.Open();
String strSQL = "select *from Students where StudName = '"  +a.ToString() + "' and StudNum = '" + studentNumber;
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strSQL);
```

Comment: And what is the error? Why we should try to guess the informations that you have on your monitor? There a lot of problems in that code.

Comment: Use parameterd instrad of concatenating strings. Read about sql injection

Comment: Be aware of SQL injection!

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom) alert!

Answer (score 2):

`StudNum = '" + studentNumber`

The Database column for studentNumber is numeric but you're half treating it as alphanumeric.

**Solution**

`StudNum = " + studentNumber`

You need to use Parameterised commands to [protect against an SQL Injection attack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev). This will also solve issues such as variables containing apostrophes and etc that would also cause your sql to fail.